# How to fix "Reset the Local Area Connection errors"

Tags: windows-7, networking

I'm getting errors saying *Reset the Local Area Connection - doesn't have a valid configuration or No Internet Access or Reset Network Adapter* on Windows 7.

Microsoft solves the problems, then in come right back with the errors and I can't access the Web.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide some details. When does it happen, did it work before, when was the first time the problem appeared?

Comment: May be private IP and default gateway IP are not in the same subnet as provided.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways you can use to get rid of this annoying error. I would recommend trying all methods until the problem is resolved.

**Reset Windows Sock And TCP/IP Settings**

Launch Command Prompt as an administrator and execute the following commands:

```
 netsh winsock reset
 netsh int tcp reset
 netsh int ip reset
```

After that, restart your computer and test again!

**Clean All Network Cached Files**

Open Command Prompt as I mentioned above and perform these commands:

```
 ipconfig /release
 ipconfig /flushdns
 ipconfig /renew
```

After that, reboot your PC and check again!

**Manual Config IP Settings**

Instead of using dynamic IP settings and let your Windows uses default IP configuration, you should manually config it, from IP, default gateway, subnet mask, as well as DNS.

[image]

Source: https://usefulpcguide.com/18773/fix-ethernet-doesnt-have-a-valid-ip-configuration-error-in-windows/

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

Open Run box (press <kbd>[image]</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>), type `CMD` and hit Enter.
In the command prompt, type:

```
netsh interface reset all (hit Enter) 

netsh winsock reset (hit Enter)
```

- Restart your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly I've seen a similar problem twice in the past week.

With both problems the user couldn't access the internet and Windows was auto-configuring the IP address with a 169.xxx.xxx.xxx address.

The first problem turned out to be a router issue (which was supplying IP addresses via DHCP) - the fix was to turn off the router, wait for 60 seconds then turn it back on. The PC was using a wireless network adapter.

The second problem turned out to be a failed Ethernet-over-power adapter.

If you don't think anything has changed on your network I'd advise the usual - turn everything off, count to 60, deep breath, turn it back on ...

Answer (score 0):

ok i have this issue for a long time. I dont like doing this daily but it works right away..  Right click your network connection icon on the bottom  right of your screen Open network and sharing center. Open change  network adapter settings. Right click LOCAL AREA CONNECTION. Click DISABLE. Wait a few seconds  (watching the icon  on  the bottom right side you will see it turn to  a red X.
right click the LOCAL AREA CONNECTION  again. Click ENABLE>
wait about 10 seconds and your back on line!
Its really fast to do once you do it one time....... This is a little trick a Cable company tech showed me.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.